# Content offset in Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, offset

I want to create my own implementation of a div with scroll, without using `overflow: scroll;`

But I can't seem to figure out how to get the content offset of a div, does anyone know?

Comment: Are you really sure you want to do that?  I mean, it's your application, but generally it's questionable to make your users figure out how your control works once they're used to the native controls they see all the time in other browser windows.  Just a thought.

I predict that getting something like that to work with arbitrary content across browsers might be tricky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure I understand what you mean by "content offset", but one way to implement scrolling-like behavior would be this:

```
<div id="a">
    <div id="b">
        Lorem ipsum dolor pipsum.
    </div>
</div>

#a {
    position: relative;
    overflow: hidden;
    height: 100px;
}
#b {
    position: absolute;
    height: 200px;
}
```

Now you could scroll `#b` within `#a` by changing the `#b`'s `top` property. Scrolling it to bottom would mean setting `top` to `-100px`, and `0` to reset.

Implementing an actual scroll-**bar** would be up to you, though. As well as things like mouse-wheel support.

Comment: Thanks, that works :)

And I didn't say I was going to implement a scrollbar ;)